# multipe linked control arrays in visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net

In vb6 there were control arrays with Index.

The index was useful: It could be used to handle a parallel set of control. In My example, there is a row of buttons, and a row of images, each button affects each image, respectively.

```
but(1)    but(2)    but(3)
img(1)    img(2)    img(3)
```

thus i could do something like...

```
but_click(index) 
    img(index).do_something()
```

Is there another way in VB.NET to do that, besides creating 2 arrays in design time and writing code to manage these arrays?

Comment: the automatic vb6 to vb.net converter used "VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.ButtonArray" to work around this

Answer (score 3):

> Is there another way in VB.NET to do that, besides creating 2 arrays in design time and writing code to manage these arrays?

No, and there shouldn’t be. This is a good thing. Many people, when coming from VB6 to VB.NET, miss control arrays. But in reality it’s the other way round: VB.NET doesn’t have control arrays because it doesn’t need them any more, controls can be put into *normal* arrays and collections (in VB6, control arrays were a *hack* to work around the fact that you couldn’t create normal arrays of controls).

The only difference is that the *forms designer* doesn’t support this. Which is also nor surprising if you think about it: control arrays are intrinsically dynamic, it makes no sense to create them statically at design time, you *have* to manage them in code.

Comment: hmmm. What If I have 1000 elements in each array? I'd need a small program just to add them to the source code, and the source would look like hell, not to mention changes to the code.

Comment: @Berry You have heard about loops, surely? And surely you don’t want to tell me that you were adding 1000 elements in VB6 via the forms designer.